# Creating a table in python docx and use small_caps (python-docx)

Tags: python, python-docx

This is what I have tried:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.shared import Pt
table = document.add_table(rows= 3, cols = 1)
row = table.rows[0]
runner = row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('Summary')
runner.bold = True
runner.small_caps = True
document.save('demo.docx')
```

I am trying to create a table and small caps the text but cannot get the syntax right

Comment: Try runner.smallCaps = True ?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured how to use small caps for text.

```
runner_font = runner.font
runner_font.size = Pt(14)
runner_font.small_caps = True
runner_font.bold = True
```

I believe bold and italic are properties that built in under both `add_run` and `font`. But for small_caps, all_caps, color can be called under `font` only.